# Since update from vaadin 22 to 23 appending a element to the shadow root breaks the component

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

### Original Question

I want to add a loading indicator overlay to the grid.
I tried to append the overlay element to the shadow root by using the **attachShadow** method.

The following code works well in vaadin 22.

```java
final Grid<String> grid = new Grid<>();
final Element element = new Element("div");
element.setText("Hello");
add(grid);
grid.getElement().attachShadow().appendChild(element);
```

When I execute the same code in vaadin 23 it breaks the component.

### Alternative solution

I tried to extend the grid component on the client side with the following typescript code

```js
import { Grid } from "@vaadin/grid";
export class CustomGrid extends Grid {
    static get is() {
        return 'custom-grid';
    }
}
customElements.define(CustomGrid.is, CustomGrid);
```

To use my custom grid in flow, I have extended the flow Grid class and added my custom typescript code with the **@JsModule** annotation.

```java
@Tag("custom-grid")
@JsModule("./src/custom-grid/custom-grid.ts")
public class CustomGrid<T> extends Grid<T> {
}
```

I used the following code to add my custom grid to the layout

```
final CustomGrid<String> grid = new CustomGrid<>();
grid.addColumn(s -> s).setHeader("Hello");
grid.setItems(List.of("Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"));
add(grid);
```

#### The problem

The items are not visible. There are just blank rows.
[image]

**ps**: extending other components like buttons or comboboxes works pretty well.

Comment: The shadow root of a reusable component should be considered an internal implementation detail of the component. This leads to me wondering what you try to achieve by adding your own elements to the shadow root of the grid?

Comment: I want to add a overlay with a little spinner to the grid while loading the data from the database. I first tried to add the overlay element directly into the grids root element. But the overlay element was not visible because of the shadow root.

Comment: I updated my original question by adding a alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with my own customization of Vaadin's Grid.
I did exactly the same as you - and it worked with v22 but it does not with v23.

Although it's a dirty hack, it works by doing the follwing:

```
final Grid<String> grid = new Grid<>();
add(grid);
grid.getElement().executeJs("elem = document.createElement(\"div\"); elem.innerHTML=\"Hallo\"; this.shadowRoot.appendChild(elem);");
```